# Copy a file into another directory's inside

Tags: file-copy

I want to copy positionXYZ into another directory's inside I want both of them.I put:

```
Tutorials myname $ cp -r positionXYZ Documents/Gerris\ Programs/Tutorials/tutorial6/
```

Then it says :

```
cp: directory Documents/Gerris Programs/Tutorials/tutorial6 does not exist
```

Tutorials is the positionXYZ's current parent directory, tutorial6 is the directory which I want to copy the file into.

Comment: Does the directory structure exist that you're copying into?

Comment: What is the output of `ls`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of these commands `pwd` and `ls`. I am 99% sure that what you want to run is `cp -r positionXYZ ~/Documents/Gerris\ Programs/Tutorials/tutorial6/` (note the `~/`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are already in

```
Documents/Gerris Programs/Tutorials/
```

so, all you need to do is:

```
cp -r positionXYZ tutorial6/
```

or if you want to use an absolute path (assuming that `Documents` is in your home directory `~`):

```
cp -r positionXYZ ~/Documents/Gerris\ Programs/Tutorials/tutorial6/
```

Comment: thnx it helped, done